# Ubuntu Boot Issue - Purple Screen

Tags: boot, grub2, gpu-driver, ubuntu-drivers

I am having issues installing/booting Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my 2009 MacBookPro.

I am able to run Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from the 'trial' mode but when I
install Ubuntu on my 1tb Samsung 860 EVO SSD and try to boot I get a
purple screen.

I've tried installing Ubuntu several times.  I also edited
the grub file to add 'nomodeset' to the grub boot loader variable:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, without success.

I also installed and ran 'boot-repair':

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XDsM7wQbNN

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved after:

1. installing 21.04 LTS
2. running the LiveMode from the trial,
3. mounting the installed drive (e.g. $ mount -t ext4 /dev/sda2 /mnt
4. editing grub file in : /mnt/etc/default/grub
   changing GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT to include "nomodeset"
5. running boot-repair after the change(s) to the grub file.
6. rebooting